# How to create iphone provisioning profile with technical role in Itunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

I have encountered a problem. My customer add me as Technical Role in his Itunes Connect account. Now I would like to test our iphone application on my iphone device. But I can not see where Provisioning profile portal anywhere. Would you please tell me how I create iphone provisioning profile with my Technical role?

I am appreciated with your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a provisioning profile, but you can request inclusion into the Team Provisioning Profile via Xcode's Organizer. After that, you need to wait until your customer approves your request.